# Связанные списки

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Хочу уточнить.
Есть код вида(простой набросок):

```
struct list{
  int data;
  list*pNext;
};
list *pHead=NULL;
void addHead(int b)
{
    list *ch=new list;
    ch->data=b;
    ch->pNext = pHead;
    pHead = ch;
}
void display (){
    list * current=pHead;
    while(current)
    {
       cout<<current->data;
       current=current->pNext;
    }

}
int main() 
{

  addHead(3);
  display();
   return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять логику в строке `list * current=pHead;` Почему *current указывает на 1-й элемент, а не на NULL, ведь в блоке `void addHead(int b)`pHead присваевается NULL.
Вроде, все написал как надо, но выводит бесконечно только последний введенный элемент. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

**Обновление**

`pHead=ch; pHead` указывает на созданную структуру, куда записалась в поле data 3, я правильно понял?
В функции display() current указывает на структуру, а если вызовов будет несколько, то *current укажет на последнею структуру или нет?

С присваиванием NULL  я ошибся, вы правы.

**Обновление 2**

Этот код стряпал я. ) Действительно, включив ее в цикл, все заработало, спасибо за внимательность. ) Тогда остался последний вопрос, как в функции `dissplay()` происходит вывод на печать, т.е. `*current`  указывает на `pHead;`, который объявлен глобально и равен налу? Значит, `*current = NULL`, соответственно, далее идет проверка `while(current){...}` (не равен ли currenr 0), но он ведь равен. Я запутался здесь. Код писал с примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что Вы написали называется стек. Тоже разновидность списка.

Я так и не понял, а что Вам тут не нравится?

Если хотите строить список, добавляя элементы в хвост, то используйте 2 указателя -- `head` и `tail` (для списка из одного элемента tail == head).

Кстати, только что был подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/374116), правда о двусвязном списке, но в целом все то же самое. Почитайте.

**Обновление**

Смысл строки:

```
list * current=pHead;
```

крайне прост.

В функции определяется локальная переменная с именем `current` и ее начальным значение становится адрес первого элемента списка. Это значение берется из глобальной переменной `pHead`.

---

Ничего вроде: "в дальнейшем *может быть выделена*" нет и в помине...

---

Если список пуст, то `pHead = 0`. Последний элемент списка тоже имеет нулевой указатель. Поэтому такой цикл `while` корректно перебирает все элементы списка.

**Обновление 2**

@dil, возьмите отладчик (или карандаш и листок бумаги) и посмотрите программу по шагам.

---

На самом деле в начале `main()` `pHead=0`. После первого вызова `addHead()` она будет равна, скажем 100000 (результату `new`). А `pNext` в структуре по этому адресу будет 0.

После второго `addHead()` `pHead` станет, например, 100016, а `pNext` в этой структуре -- 100000 (т.е. предыдущее значение `pHead`).

И т.д.

`pHead` будет всегда указывать на *первый по порядку* (но *последний в смысле времени создания* (только что созданный)) элемент списка (он же стек в данной реализации).

Answer (score 0):

> в блоке void addHead(int b)pHead присваевается NULL

В функции addHead `pHead` присваивается `ch`, вообще-то.

Хотя нет, ей присваивается `new list`. pNext - это элемент структуры, в котором хранится указатель на соседнюю ноду, т.к. это голова, соседней ноды просто нет.

Я давно изучал сишку, причем довольно поверхностно, но я бы рекомендовал скорее написать этот код самому, потому что приведенный пример очень, эм, странный. В display будет бесконечный цикл, т.к. последняя строчка должна входить в цикл, чтобы условие менялось. Если проблема цикла будет решена, и вызовов будет несколько, то каждый вызов будет обрабатываться одинаково - посмотрите внимательно на первую строчку.

**Обновление**

Я давно изучал сишку, причем довольно поверхностно, но я бы рекомендовал скорее написать этот код самому, потому что приведенный пример очень, эм, странный. В display будет бесконечный цикл, т.к. последняя строчка должна входить в цикл, чтобы условие менялось. Если проблема цикла будет решена, и вызовов будет несколько, то каждый вызов будет обрабатываться одинаково - посмотрите внимательно на первую строчку.

**Обновление 2**

После вызова `addHead()` `pHead` уже не равен нулевому указателю.

**Обновление N**

[[@dil](/users/24806/dil)](/users/24806/dil), это ваш код, как вы его написали - так он и будет выполняться) Но вообще смысл addHead явно в том, чтобы этот самый head создать, а элементы в список добавляются каким-то другим путем. Т.е. если вы добавите миллион записей, pHead все равно будет указывать на голову, и отсчет будет начинаться тоже оттуда.